# Override CSS values for slider background

Tags: html, css, overriding

I am using a java slider. [DEMO](http://demo.sequencejs.com/modern-slide-in/) The slider uses one background for all the slides (bg-sequence.jpg). I would like each slide to have its own background. How would I achieve this? Here is the CSS and HTML code.

Thank you

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/**
 * Theme Name: Modern Slide In
 * Version: 2.0.0
 * Theme URL: http://sequencejs.com/themes/modern-slide-in/
 *
 * A minimalist theme for showcasing products
 *
 * This theme is powered by Sequence.js - The
 * responsive CSS animation framework for creating unique sliders,
 * presentations, banners, and other step-based applications.
 *
 * Author: Ian Lunn
 * Author URL: http://ianlunn.co.uk/
 *
 * Theme License: http://sequencejs.com/licenses/#free-theme
 * Sequence.js Licenses: http://sequencejs.com/licenses/
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Ian Lunn Design Limited unless otherwise stated.
 */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:700|Source+Sans+Pro:300);

body,
html,
.seq {
  /* Uncomment to make the theme full-screen */
  /* width: 100% !important; */
  /* max-width: 100% !important; */
  /* height: 100% !important; */
  /* max-height: 100% !important; */
}

.seq {
  position: relative;
  background: #D9D9D9 url("../images/bg-sequence.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Dimensions */
  height: 360px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  /* Hide anything that goes beyond the boundaries of the Sequence container */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Center the Sequence container on the page */
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}


.seq .seq-preloader {
  background: #D9D9D9;
}

.seq .seq-screen,
.seq .seq-canvas,
.seq .seq-canvas > * {
  /* Reset the canvas and steps for more browser consistency */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.seq .seq-canvas > * {
  position: absolute;
}

.seq.seq-fallback {
  /* Fallback styles */
}

.seq.seq-fallback .seq-canvas {
  max-width: 1280px;
}

.seq.seq-fallback .seq-pagination li {
  position: relative;
}

.seq.seq-fallback .seq-pagination li img {
  border: none;
}

.seq.seq-fallback .seq-pagination li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.seq.seq-fallback .seq-next:focus,
.seq.seq-fallback .seq-next:hover,
.seq.seq-fallback .seq-prev:focus,
.seq.seq-fallback .seq-prev:hover,
.seq.seq-fallback .seq-pagination li:focus,
.seq.seq-fallback .seq-pagination li:hover {
  top: -4px;
}

.seq .seq-canvas {
  max-width: 1280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.seq .seq-nav,
.seq .seq-pagination {
  /* Hide navigation when JS is disabled */
  display: none;
}

.seq.seq-active .seq-nav {
  /* Show navigation and pagination if JS is enabled */
  display: block;
}

.seq .seq-nav {
  /* Styles for next/previous buttons and pagination */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: none;
}

.seq .seq-next,
.seq .seq-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -33px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 66px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  /* Image replacement */
  border: 0;
  font: 0/0 a;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: transparent;
}

.seq .seq-next {
  right: 20px;
  background: url("../images/bt-next.png");
}

.seq .seq-next:focus,
.seq .seq-next:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
}

.seq .seq-prev {
  left: 20px;
  background: url("../images/bt-prev.png");
}

.seq .seq-prev:focus,
.seq .seq-prev:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
}

.seq .seq-model,
.seq .seq-title {
  position: absolute;
}

.seq .seq-title {
  bottom: 5%;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  width: 95%;
}

.seq .seq-model {
  bottom: 15%;
  height: 81%;
  width: 100%;
  /* Don't allow the image to exceed its original height */
  max-height: 568px;
}

.seq .seq-model img {
  /* Don't allow the image to exceed its original height */
  max-height: 568px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(60px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(60px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(60px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  -webkit-transition-properties: transform, opacity;
  transition-properties: transform, opacity;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out !important;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out !important;
}

.seq .seq-title br {
  display: none;
}

.seq .seq-title h2,
.seq .seq-title h3 {
  display: block;
  width: 98%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  -webkit-transition-properties: opacity;
  transition-properties: opacity;
}

.seq .seq-title h2 {
  padding: .2em 1%;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  float: left;
}

.seq .seq-title h3 {
  display: none;
  clear: left;
}

.seq .seq-in {
  /* Animate in positions for content */
}

.seq .seq-in .seq-model img {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.seq .seq-in .seq-title h2,
.seq .seq-in .seq-title h3 {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.seq .seq-out {
  /* Animate out positions for content */
}

.seq .seq-out .seq-model img {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-60px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-60px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-60px, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.seq .seq-out .seq-title h2,
.seq .seq-out .seq-title h3 {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .seq {
    /* Make the container 16:9 but no bigger than 90% of the screen height */
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 90vh;
    min-height: 360px;
    /* Move the background radial to the left */
    background-position: 50% 100%;
  }

  .seq:before {
    /* Make an element a certain aspect ratio */
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
  }

  .seq .seq-screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .seq .seq-canvas > *:before {
    /* Vertically align the content using a :before element */
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .seq .seq-model,
  .seq .seq-title {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 5% 0 2.5%;
  }

  .seq .seq-model {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
  }

  .seq .seq-model img {
    float: right;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(60px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(60px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(60px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-properties: transform, opacity;
    transition-properties: transform, opacity;
  }

  .seq .seq-title {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 12.5%;
  }

  .seq .seq-title h2,
  .seq .seq-title h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    -webkit-transition-properties: transform, opacity;
    transition-properties: transform, opacity;
  }

  .seq .seq-title h2 {
    margin-bottom: .4em;
    padding: .2em .6em;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-120px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-120px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-120px, 0, 0);
  }

  .seq .seq-title h3 {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(120px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(120px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(120px, 0, 0);
  }

  .seq .seq-in {
    /* Animate in positions for content */
  }

  .seq .seq-in .seq-model img {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .seq .seq-out {
    /* Animate out positions for content */
  }

  .seq .seq-out .seq-model img {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-60px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-60px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-60px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .seq.seq-active .seq-pagination {
    /* Show navigation and pagination if JS is enabled */
    display: block;
  }

  .seq .seq-pagination {
    pointer-events: none;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    max-width: 1240px;
    text-align: right;
  }

  .seq .seq-pagination li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .seq .seq-pagination li img {
    opacity: .4;
    pointer-events: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
    transition-duration: .2s;
    -webkit-transition-properties: transform, opacity;
    transition-properties: transform, opacity;
  }

  .seq .seq-pagination li.seq-current img {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .seq .seq-pagination li:focus img,
  .seq .seq-pagination li:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 860px) {
  .seq .seq-model {
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 27.5%;
  }

  .seq .seq-title {
    width: 42.5%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }

  .seq .seq-title br {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1020px) {
  .seq .seq-model {
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 32.5%;
  }

  .seq .seq-title {
    width: 47.5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1120px) {
  .seq .seq-model {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 37.5%;
  }

  .seq .seq-title {
    width: 52.5%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3 / 2), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi), (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
  .seq {
    /* Apply Retina (@2x) Images */
  }

  .seq .seq-next {
    background: url("../images/bt-next@2x.png");
    background-size: 35px 66px;
  }

  .seq .seq-prev {
    background: url("../images/bt-prev@2x.png");
    background-size: 35px 66px;
  }
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=sequence-theme.modern-slide-in.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Modern Slide In - Sequence.js Theme</title>
  <link href="css/sequence-theme.modern-slide-in.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

  <div id="sequence" class="seq">

    <div class="seq-screen">
      <ul class="seq-canvas">
        <li class="seq-in">
          <div class="seq-model">
            <img data-seq src="images/model1.png" alt="A female model with long curly brown hair wears a gray sweater, brown shorts, bright yellow socks, and black high heel shoes. She raises one leg, and tilts her head to the side" />
          </div>

          <div class="seq-title">
            <h2 data-seq>Title</h2>
            <h3 data-seq>Information</h3>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>


          <div class="seq-model"> 
            <img data-seq src="images/model2.png" alt="A pale-skin female model with dark eye shadow and tied up hair wears dark green gloves, gray linen boots, and a woolen lined hood on a black zip-up jacket over a black top and shorts. She holds her jacket open with both hands and slightly raises her left knee whilst looking to the floor" />
          </div>

          <div class="seq-title">
            <h2 data-seq>Create Unique Animated Themes</h2>
            <h3 data-seq>For sliders, presentations, <br />banners, and other step-based applications</h3>
          </div>


        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="seq-model">
            <img data-seq src="images/model3.png" alt="A pale-skin female model with platted hair wears a dark button-up jacket with gray shorts, black tights, brown shoes, and black gloves. She throws both arms back and raises one knee -- as if mid-jump -- whilst looking into the distance" />
          </div>

          <div class="seq-title">
            <h2 data-seq>Rapid Development of Step-Based Applications</h2>
            <h3 data-seq>All of the JavaScript functionality you need built-in</h3>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <fieldset class="seq-nav" aria-controls="sequence" aria-label="Slider buttons">
      <button type="button" class="seq-prev" aria-label="Previous">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" class="seq-next" aria-label="Next">Next</button>
    </fieldset>

    <ul role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination" class="seq-pagination">
      <li><a href="#step1" rel="step1" title="Go to slide 1"><img src="images/weed-leaf-leafcircle48.png" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#step2" rel="step2" title="Go to slide 2"><img src="images/weed-leaf-leafcircle48.png" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#step3" rel="step3" title="Go to slide 3"><img src="images/weed-leaf-leafcircle48.png" /></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="scripts/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/hammer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/sequence.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/sequence-theme.modern-slide-in.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried youself? Just copy and pasting your CSS/HTML and saying 'make this do this' isn't really what we're here for. If you could at least cut out the 'fluff' CSS, and show us what **you** have tried to achieve, we may get somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could target each slide using the CSS `nth-of-type` pseudo class

```
.seq-canvas li:nth-of-type(1) {
   background:#000;
}
```